# Как можно сделать отображение окна tkinter внутри другой программы

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, разработка-игр

Как можно сделать так чтоб программа tkinter отображалась лишь когда другая программа открыта на весь экран, например: программа tkinter активна лишь внутри окна игры csgo когда игра сворачиваеться то и программа сварачиваеться, и обратно

Comment: А csgo во весь экран открыт?

Comment: Можно задать свойство по верх остальных окон, а вот свернуть вместе с игрой это уже надо поработать.